# Android architecture for big customizable tools app

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, mvp, android-databinding

### **The background:**

I have worked on a tools app for configuring physical devices, currently it supports one device. It is written in standard `Android` using `RxJava` and `Dagger`and doesn't implement an architectural pattern.

### **The task:**

The app should be able to support 3 additional devices. Users can choose between devices and depending on the device, the functionalities will differ. This means, that in some views additional options need to be shown whereas for some devices, options need to be removed.

### The problem:

I need to refactor this app to make it enhanceable for the additional devices to be added and also to make it testable, but I'm not sure yet how to structure the app for the upcoming changes.
As a means of architecture, I want to use `MVVM` or `MVP`, but I'm undecided which pattern would fit my needs better as I'm not well adversed with both.

This is how I would plan to proceed:

- Create a singleton call DeviceConfiguration that will keep track of the current selected device and knows which device is capable of which functionalities.
- Create an Interface called Device, which all Device Classes will implement, defining the base minimum methods all devices have in common.
- When the user switches to another `Activity`, the DeviceConfiguration checks which device is currently selected and will set the correct Device for the View/Presenter/ViewModel.
- At the start of the Activity, a setup method in onCreate will show/hide the options available for the Device from the data given by the DeviceConfiguration.
- Clicking somewhere inside a screen will call Device.doSomething() which will use the device set at the beginning and use the device specific call (though I'm not sure how to handle it yet if the device doesn't have this functionality, still implement the call and just leave the method empty?)

### **The question:**

This is what I have in mind, but would this be a good structure to handle similar functionalities for different devices? 
Is it possible to test an app with this kind of setup or would it be better to create own Activities/layouts for the appropriate devices? I'm especially unsure if this works well with `MVVM` if not only the data, but also general content and views inside a layout need to change dynamically.

I'm looking for good practice to make the app cleaner and better testable, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to check out [Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) repository. It is provided by Google, you have example of MVP and MVVM architecture implementations with/without Dagger2 and RxJava. You can also check out [Mosby](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/mvp/) library. If you are beginner it is IMO better to learn on some proven implementation than overenginer your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is a big decision to start learning and using best practices for refactoring an old project or even starting a new project.

I would suggest you to take a look at this sample project which I have done using **MVP**, **Dagger**, **RxJava**, **Retrofit** and also contains different type of **Mock** tests.

> http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers

I hope it helps :)